# node, socket.io - authorization fail

Tags: node.js, socket.io

This is a skeleton of my app.js file.
What I don't understand is way it doesn't read and print "log authorisation".
I followed this https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Authorizing

```
var express = require('express');
mongoose = require('mongoose');
var MongoStore = require('connect-mongo')(express);
app = express();

// costants
var SITE_SECRET = 'xxx';

// mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://127.0.0.1/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
db.once('open', function callback () {
    console.log('Mongoose connection is now opened');
});

// pass same objects from Express to Socket.IO so they match
var parseCookie = express.cookieParser(SITE_SECRET);
var store = new MongoStore({
  mongoose_connection: mongoose.connection,
  db: mongoose.connections[0].db
});

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('host', '127.0.0.1');
    app.set('port', 1111);
    // init cookie-session
    app.use(parseCookie);
    app.use(express.session({
        secret : SITE_SECRET
        ,store  : store
        ,cookie: { maxAge: new Date(Date.now() + (1000*60*60*24*30*12)) }
    }));
});

// create and start server
var server = require('http').createServer(app)
server.listen(app.get('port'));

// socket.io
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.configure(function() {
  console.log('log configure <-- it read this. ok!');
  io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {
    console.log("log authorisation <-- but it doesn't read this. why??");
    if (handshake.headers.cookie) {
      parseCookie(handshake, null, function() {
       handshake.sessionID = handshake.signedCookies['connect.sid'];
        store.get(handshake.sessionID, function(err, session) {
            callback(null, true);
        });
      });
    } else {
      // they client has no session yet, don't let them connect
      callback('No session.', false);
    }
  });
});

clients = {};
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // save to a global object
  console.log('save session');
  var session = socket.handshake.sessionID;
  clients[session] = socket;
  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    console.log('remove session');
    delete clients[session];
  });
});

// routes
app.get('/on', function(req, res){
  var socket = clients[req.sessionID];
  socket.on('test', function (data) {
   console.log(data);
  });
});
app.get('/emit', function(req, res){
  var socket = clients[req.sessionID];
  socket.emit('test', "ciao");
  console.log("emit");
});
```

when I start the server on the terminal I see this:

```
starting `node app.js`
Mongoose connection is now opened
info  - socket.io started
log configure
```

And if I load the page "/on"
the error is:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'on' of undefined
```

I'm stack here from too much... What's wrong in this?
Maybe someone had the same problem...

Comment: Are you sure that req.sessionID is produce the same result as socket.handshake.sessionID?

Comment: how can I check it? ... because also when it loads the page I can't see in the terminal the log **"save session"** ... what can I do?

Comment: Why did you cannot see in the terminal? Simple console.log did not work? Do you start node and cannot use console.log at all?

Comment: console.log works great, only in this case it doesn't print anything inside **io.set('authorization', function(handshake, callback) {**
and also inside **io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {**.
Is for this reason I can't know if sessionIDs are the same, because they are not set :(

Comment: On whatever reason, I think you should declare all socket.on inside "io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket)". It should flow better in your app because listener shouldn't be listen multiple times or else you will most likely end up receive multiple response. You should use socket.id instead of that session id too.

Comment: Bump. got the same issue. Any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

try making `socket.io` listen to `server` port, you define `1111` as a port for server and `8080` for `socket.io` , you application is available for access at `localhost:1111`.

short example

```
var server = http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});

io.listen(server);
```